# python: change dataframe type data to have pandas.describe for numeric

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

My goal is to analyze a ndarray created by the function sklearn.train_test_split. Actually they are two ndarry of this type:

```
N_sample.dtype.name
```

and it returns *'object'* and the same for

```
R_sample.dtype.name
```

Let me explain how I obtained those data. I copied all text from [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data) and pasted in an empty file named iris.cvs file. I saved it in the same folder of my project.
So, I wrote my python script:

```
import pandas
from sklearn import model_selection
names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
dataset = pandas.read_csv('iris.cvs', names=names)
array = dataset.values
N = array[:,0:4]
R = array[:,4]
N_sample, N_test, R_sample, R_test = model_selection.train_test_split(N, R, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)
```

Therefore, I have:

```
N_sample.shape
```

that returns *(120,4)* and

```
R_sample.shape
```

that returns *(120,)*

So to create the dataset I used this:

```
new_arr=numpy.column_stack((N_sample,R_sample))
dateN=pandas.DataFrame(data =new_arr, columns=names)
#names was created before with the correct matches
```

The problem is that if I ask:

```
dateN.describe()
```

It returns count, unique, top, etc... but I want mean, std, etc...
I tried different methods, like casting data of N_sample but it doesn't work, like:

```
pandas.to_numeric(dateN,downcast='float', errors='ignore')
```

but it's not possible because it needs just list, etc...Or I used this method:

```
N_sample.astype(float,casting='unsafe')
```

but finally it doesn't change the result.

Moreover, if I do:

```
dateN.iloc[:,0:4] = dateN.iloc[:,0:4].apply(pandas.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
dateN.dtypes
```

it returns:

```
sepal-length    object
sepal-width     object
petal-length    object
petal-width     object
class           object
dtype: object
```

So nothing's changed.
How could I solve? How to make the dataset numeric so that I can get mean std, etc...?

Comment: Please post a small reproducible sample data set.

Comment: if your data are all numerical, the result of your train test split should be numeric too ( not object). For instance if everything in your original dataset are float64 then the result of train test split should be also float64. So, I recommend to first check your data before train test split. I am sure that not everything in your original data are numeric.

Comment: Read below my explanation

Comment: @MaxU, now you can try by yourself what's the problem

Comment: @SPS, `NameError: name 'model_selection' is not defined`

Comment: @MaxU, sorry I missed the importing of libraries. Try now

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following demo:

we will start from the DF consisting of all numeric columns:

```
In [282]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 3), columns=list('abc'))

In [283]: df
Out[283]:
          a         b         c
0  0.357395  0.641735  0.959405
1  0.941251  0.966066  0.626380
2  0.966839  0.388960  0.411612

In [284]: df.dtypes
Out[284]:
a    float64
b    float64
c    float64
dtype: object

In [285]: df.describe()
Out[285]:
              a         b         c
count  3.000000  3.000000  3.000000
mean   0.755162  0.665587  0.665799
std    0.344714  0.289292  0.276016
min    0.357395  0.388960  0.411612
25%    0.649323  0.515347  0.518996
50%    0.941251  0.641735  0.626380
75%    0.954045  0.803901  0.792893
max    0.966839  0.966066  0.959405
```

Now let's change a **single cell** with a string value:

```
In [286]: df.loc[0, 'b'] = 'XXXXXXXXX'

In [287]: df
Out[287]:
          a          b         c
0  0.357395  XXXXXXXXX  0.959405
1  0.941251   0.966066  0.626380
2  0.966839    0.38896  0.411612
```

as a result the whole column became `string` column:

```
In [288]: df.dtypes
Out[288]:
a    float64
b     object   # <--- NOTE !!!
c    float64
dtype: object
```

and it has disappeared from `df.describe()`

```
In [289]: df.describe()
Out[289]:
              a         c
count  3.000000  3.000000
mean   0.755162  0.665799
std    0.344714  0.276016
min    0.357395  0.411612
25%    0.649323  0.518996
50%    0.941251  0.626380
75%    0.954045  0.792893
max    0.966839  0.959405
```

if `all` our columns aren't numeric, `df.describe()` will give us different `non-numeric` statistics:

```
In [290]: df.astype(str).describe()
Out[290]:
                     a          b               c
count                3          3               3
unique               3          3               3
top     0.357394893221  XXXXXXXXX  0.411612214836
freq                 1          1               1
```

and when you use [`pd.to_numeric(..., errors='ignore')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) the column dtype will NOT be changed:

```
In [291]: df['b'] = pd.to_numeric(df['b'], errors='ignore')

In [292]: df.dtypes
Out[292]:
a    float64
b     object   # <--- NOTE !!!
c    float64
dtype: object
```

As a solution you can use `errors='coerce'` - this will replace all values that can't be converted to numeric dtype with `NaN`'s:

```
In [293]: df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

In [294]: df.dtypes
Out[294]:
a    float64
b    float64
c    float64
dtype: object

In [295]: df
Out[295]:
          a         b         c
0  0.357395       NaN  0.959405
1  0.941251  0.966066  0.626380
2  0.966839  0.388960  0.411612
```

now `df.describe()` will work `numeric` again:

```
In [296]: df.describe()
Out[296]:
              a         b         c
count  3.000000  2.000000  3.000000
mean   0.755162  0.677513  0.665799
std    0.344714  0.408076  0.276016
min    0.357395  0.388960  0.411612
25%    0.649323  0.533236  0.518996
50%    0.941251  0.677513  0.626380
75%    0.954045  0.821789  0.792893
max    0.966839  0.966066  0.959405
```

Comment: My starting dataset is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) that I processed with:  `array = dataset.values
N = array[:,0:4]
F = array[:,4]
N_sample, N_validation, R_sample, R_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(N, F, test_size=0.2, random_state=7) ` But if I do dataset.describe I get the numeric information, if I analyze the new dataset with N_sample + R_sample no. That's my issue that I don't understand and I can't solve. How could I manage my new dataset to make what I want? Thanks

Comment: No one else could help me?

Comment: @SPS, i think i've shown you how to deal with that, no?

Comment: your answer was useful to explain me what happens, and it's great, but `dateN[:,0:4] = dateN[:,0:4].apply(pandas.to_numeric, errors='coerce') ` or similar doesn't work in my case. As you can test by yourself, the first four columns in the dataset are just numbers, so we can do the change. But how? That's the problem! Thanks

Comment: `dateN.iloc[:,0:4] = dateN.iloc[:,0:4].apply(pandas.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` ?

Comment: it doesn't work! In fact I have this: `datiN.iloc[:,0:4] =dateN.iloc[:,0:4].apply(pandas.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
dateN.dtypes`   which returns this: ` sepal-length    object
sepal-width     object
petal-length    object
petal-width     object
class           object
dtype: object ` so it seems nothing's changed

Comment: @SPS, i 'd recommend you to open a new question and post there a small __reproducible__ data set and your desired data set. Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 0):

Most sSKLearn methods accept Pandas.DataFrame's so there is no need to convert your data into Numpy arrays and back.

Demo:

read CSV:

```
In [93]: dataset = pd.read_csv(url, names=names)

In [94]: dataset
Out[94]:
     sepal-length  sepal-width  petal-length  petal-width           class
0             5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2     Iris-setosa
1             4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2     Iris-setosa
2             4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2     Iris-setosa
3             4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2     Iris-setosa
4             5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2     Iris-setosa
..            ...          ...           ...          ...             ...
145           6.7          3.0           5.2          2.3  Iris-virginica
146           6.3          2.5           5.0          1.9  Iris-virginica
147           6.5          3.0           5.2          2.0  Iris-virginica
148           6.2          3.4           5.4          2.3  Iris-virginica
149           5.9          3.0           5.1          1.8  Iris-virginica

[150 rows x 5 columns]
```

categorizing and factorizing `class` column:

```
In [95]: dataset['class'] = dataset['class'].astype('category')

In [96]: dataset['class_num'] = dataset['class'].cat.codes

In [97]: dataset
Out[97]:
     sepal-length  sepal-width  petal-length  petal-width           class  class_num
0             5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2     Iris-setosa          0
1             4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2     Iris-setosa          0
2             4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2     Iris-setosa          0
3             4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2     Iris-setosa          0
4             5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2     Iris-setosa          0
..            ...          ...           ...          ...             ...        ...
145           6.7          3.0           5.2          2.3  Iris-virginica          2
146           6.3          2.5           5.0          1.9  Iris-virginica          2
147           6.5          3.0           5.2          2.0  Iris-virginica          2
148           6.2          3.4           5.4          2.3  Iris-virginica          2
149           5.9          3.0           5.1          1.8  Iris-virginica          2

[150 rows x 6 columns]
```

splitting dataset into train and test sets:

```
In [98]: N_sample, N_test, R_sample, R_test = \
    ...:     train_test_split(dataset.iloc[:, :4], dataset.iloc[:, -1],
    ...:                      test_size=0.2, random_state=7)
    ...:

In [99]: N_sample
Out[99]:
     sepal-length  sepal-width  petal-length  petal-width
126           6.2          2.8           4.8          1.8
79            5.7          2.6           3.5          1.0
22            4.6          3.6           1.0          0.2
139           6.9          3.1           5.4          2.1
74            6.4          2.9           4.3          1.3
..            ...          ...           ...          ...
142           5.8          2.7           5.1          1.9
92            5.8          2.6           4.0          1.2
103           6.3          2.9           5.6          1.8
67            5.8          2.7           4.1          1.0
25            5.0          3.0           1.6          0.2

[120 rows x 4 columns]

In [100]: N_sample.dtypes
Out[100]:
sepal-length    float64
sepal-width     float64
petal-length    float64
petal-width     float64
dtype: object

In [101]: R_sample
Out[101]:
126    2
79     1
22     0
139    2
74     1
      ..
142    2
92     1
103    2
67     1
25     0
Name: class_num, Length: 120, dtype: int8

In [102]: R_sample.dtype
Out[102]: dtype('int8')
```

As you see **all** columns are of numeric dtypes...

Comment: So, practically you added a new column to the dataset representing names with numbers, and then you used just a dataset of 'numbers' to obtain what I want...mmm...but why can we not transform just the fourth columns of interest for my describe outputs?

Comment: @SPS, transform to what ?

Comment: what I mean, it's not to touch the last column, and change data type of the other columns

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do... SKLearn methods don't like string (object) dtypes, so you will need to convert them anyway. I've provided you a solution which does exactly that.